# Linking merchant account from another location

Tags: google-play, merchant-account

We are two developers. I am from the Philippines and the other developer from London, UK. We are done with the game and started adding in-app purchase. I just learned that I cannot open a merchant account as Philippines is not included. But my teammate can since he is in UK. Is it legal if he opens up a merchant account from UK and links to my developer account? Can we legally then implement in-app purchase?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to open a bank account in the UK through a legal representative living there.

The registration process is very thorough in asking you to enter bank information details, so Google will reject countries that are not in [this list](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/150324?hl=en). Sad, but it's the truth no thanks in part due to legal restrictions worldwide.

Comment: That sucks! They shuld add PH.. :(

Comment: I know. Unfortunately, it is very likely that it will take such a long time, if at all, before less e-commerce-friendly nations would be added to the list.

Answer (score 1):

Your teammate should open his own developer account and use that to open a merchant account.